# Shell : Display a folder's files content (ls) , search for a file name and display it

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a folder which may contain several files.  Among those files I have files like these:

- test.xml
- test.jar
- test.jarGENERATED
- dev.project.jar
- ...

and many other files.  To get only the "**dev.project.jar**" I have executed:

```
ls | grep ^{{dev}}.*.jar$
```

This displays the file with its properties for me.  However, I only want the file name **(only the file name string)**

**How to rectify it??**

Comment: You wrote "This displays the file with its properties for me". This sounds like the normal output of `ls -l files*`. Are you sure you don't have an alias for `ls` set someplaces? (`alias | grep '^ls'`). You should edit your Q to show your current output AND your required output from that list of files. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` and `grep` are both unnecessary here. The shell will show you any file name matches for a wildcard:

```
echo dev.*.jar
```

(`ls dev.*.jar` without options will do something similar per se; if you see anything more than the filename, perhaps you have stupidly defined `alias ls='ls -l'` or something like that?)

The argument to `grep` should be a regular expression; what you specified would match `{{dev}}` and not `dev`, though in the absence of quoting, your shell might have expanded the braces. The proper regex would be `grep '^dev\..*\.jar$'` where the single quotes protect the regex from any shell expansions, and `.` matches any character, and `*` repeats that character as many times as possible. To match a literal dot, we backslash-escape it.

Just printing a file name is rarely very useful; often times, you actually want something like

```
for file in ./dev.*.jar; do
    echo "$file"
    : probably do more things with "$file"
done
```

though if that's all you want, maybe prefer `printf` over `echo`, which also lets you avoid the loop:

```
printf '%s\n' dev.*.jar
```